# Crosshair cursor becoming translucent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html2canvas

I am trying to capture the screen shot using a package called `html2canvas` where I want to add the crosshair cursor while selecting the area on the webpage. Is there any way to make the cursor work properly.

**ScreenCapture.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

export default class ScreenCapture extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    onStartCapture: () => null,
    onEndCapture: () => null
  }

  state = {
    on: false,
    startX: 0,
    startY: 0,
    endX: 0,
    endY: 0,
    crossHairsTop: 0,
    crossHairsLeft: 0,
    isMouseDown: false,
    windowWidth: 0,
    windowHeight: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    cropPositionTop: 0,
    cropPositionLeft: 0,
    cropWidth: 0,
    cropHeigth: 0,
    imageURL: ''
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.handleWindowResize()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize)
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize)
  }

  handleWindowResize = () => {
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

    this.setState({
      windowWidth,
      windowHeight
    })
  }

  handStartCapture = () => this.setState({ on: true })

  handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    const { isMouseDown, windowWidth, windowHeight, startX, startY, borderWidth } = this.state

    let cropPositionTop = startY
    let cropPositionLeft = startX
    const endX = e.clientX
    const endY = e.clientY
    const isStartTop = endY >= startY
    const isStartBottom = endY <= startY
    const isStartLeft = endX >= startX
    const isStartRight = endX <= startX
    const isStartTopLeft = isStartTop && isStartLeft
    const isStartTopRight = isStartTop && isStartRight
    const isStartBottomLeft = isStartBottom && isStartLeft
    const isStartBottomRight = isStartBottom && isStartRight
    let newBorderWidth = borderWidth
    let cropWidth = 0
    let cropHeigth = 0

    if (isMouseDown) {
      if (isStartTopLeft) {
        newBorderWidth = `${startY}px ${windowWidth - endX}px ${windowHeight - endY}px ${startX}px`
        cropWidth = endX - startX
        cropHeigth = endY - startY
      }

      if (isStartTopRight) {
        newBorderWidth = `${startY}px ${windowWidth - startX}px ${windowHeight - endY}px ${endX}px`
        cropWidth = startX - endX
        cropHeigth = endY - startY
        cropPositionLeft = endX
      }

      if (isStartBottomLeft) {
        newBorderWidth = `${endY}px ${windowWidth - endX}px ${windowHeight - startY}px ${startX}px`
        cropWidth = endX - startX
        cropHeigth = startY - endY
        cropPositionTop = endY
      }

      if (isStartBottomRight) {
        newBorderWidth = `${endY}px ${windowWidth - startX}px ${windowHeight - startY}px ${endX}px`
        cropWidth = startX - endX
        cropHeigth = startY - endY
        cropPositionLeft = endX
        cropPositionTop = endY
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      crossHairsTop: e.clientY,
      crossHairsLeft: e.clientX,
      borderWidth: newBorderWidth,
      cropWidth,
      cropHeigth,
      cropPositionTop: cropPositionTop,
      cropPositionLeft: cropPositionLeft
    })
  }

  handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    const startX = e.clientX
    const startY = e.clientY

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      startX,
      startY,
      cropPositionTop: startY,
      cropPositionLeft: startX,
      isMouseDown: true,
      borderWidth: `${prevState.windowWidth}px ${prevState.windowHeight}px`
    }))
  }

  handleMouseUp = (e) => {
    this.handleClickTakeScreenShot()
    this.setState({
      on: false,
      isMouseDown: false,
      borderWidth: 0
    })
  }

  handleClickTakeScreenShot = () => {
    const { cropPositionTop, cropPositionLeft, cropWidth, cropHeigth } = this.state
    const body = document.querySelector('body')

    html2canvas(body).then(canvas => {
      let croppedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
      let croppedCanvasContext = croppedCanvas.getContext('2d')

      croppedCanvas.width = cropWidth;
      croppedCanvas.height = cropHeigth;

      croppedCanvasContext.drawImage(canvas, cropPositionLeft, cropPositionTop, cropWidth, cropHeigth, 0, 0, cropWidth, cropHeigth);

      this.props.onEndCapture(croppedCanvas.toDataURL())
    });
  }

  renderChild = () => {
    const { children } = this.props

    const props = {
      onStartCapture: this.handStartCapture
    }

    if (typeof children === 'function') return children(props)
    return children
  }

  render() {
    const {
      on,
      crossHairsTop,
      crossHairsLeft,
      borderWidth,
      isMouseDown,
      imageURL
    } = this.state

    if (!on) return this.renderChild()

    return (
      <div
        onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
      >
        {this.renderChild()}
        <div
          className={`overlay ${isMouseDown && 'highlighting'}`}
          style={{ borderWidth }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

<kbd>[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-screen-capture-gdx8br)</kbd>

Also, I've tried adding cursor using css pseudo elements. But, the cursor getting added in the screen capture if dragged from any side(other than top left to bottom right).

<kbd>[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/screen-capture-soq)</kbd>

Comment: The color of the crosshair cursor is calculated by FFFFFF - bg_color. Given your bg_color is 0.5, your cursor color is very close to it showing "translucent". May try a different bg_color like 0.8.